# Save State of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a app with RecylerView populated with data form an online server. It has a custom layout with a favorite button that when clicked the icon changes.I have a problem trying to save state of a selected view on the RecyclerView. The RecyclerView does not save the selected state on scrolling back up. Kindly help.

Model Class

```
package com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsModel;

/**
 * Created by 4331 on 25/09/2015.
 */
public class Latest {
    public String excerpt;
    public String articleImage;
    public String articleUrl;
    public boolean mfavourite;



    public boolean isFavourite(){
        return mfavourite;
    }

    public String getArticleUrl() {
        return articleUrl;
    }

    public void setArticleUrl(String articleUrl) {
        this.articleUrl = articleUrl;
    }

    public String getExcerpt() {
        return excerpt;
    }

    public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }

    public String getArticleImage() {
        return articleImage;
    }

    public void setArticleImage(String articleImage) {
        this.articleImage = articleImage;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
package com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nispok.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.nispok.snackbar.SnackbarManager;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.R;
import com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.ReadArticleActivity;
import com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsModel.Latest;
import com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.util.SharedPreferenceRecycler;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4331 on 29/09/2015.
 */
public class OtherNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OtherNewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Latest> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityGplus";
    SharedPreferenceRecycler sharedPreference = new SharedPreferenceRecycler();
    public OtherNewsAdapter(Context context, List<Latest> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_other_news, null);
        ViewHolder mh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final Latest feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder).build();

        //download and display image from url
        imageLoader.displayImage(feedItem.getArticleImage(), viewHolder.thumbnail, options);

//        Glide.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getArticleImage())
//                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
//                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
//                .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);

        viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getExcerpt()));

    viewHolder.articleUrl.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getArticleUrl()));

        viewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ReadArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("articleUrl", viewHolder.articleUrl.getText().toString());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        /*If a product exists in shared preferences then set heart_red drawable
         * and set a tag*/
            if (checkFavoriteItem(feedItem)) {
                viewHolder.favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                viewHolder.favImage.setSelected(true);
                viewHolder.favImage.setTag("red");
                hashMap.get(i);
            }
         else {
                viewHolder.favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                viewHolder.favImage.setSelected(false);
                viewHolder.favImage.setTag("grey");
        }
        viewHolder.title.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setId(R.id.otherImage);
        viewHolder.articleUrl.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OtherNewsRowHolder holder = (OtherNewsRowHolder) view.getTag();
            int position = holder.getPosition();
            Latest feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getExcerpt(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    /*Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Latest checkProduct) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<Latest> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(mContext);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (Latest product : favorites) {
                if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected ImageView thumbnail, favImage;
        protected TextView title,articleUrl;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherImage);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherExcerpt);
            this.articleUrl=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherUrl);
            this.favImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
            favImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String tag = favImage.getTag().toString();
            if(!favImage.isSelected()) {
                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext, feedItemList.get(getItemCount() - 1));
//                    Toast.makeText(mContext,                        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
//                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //SnackBack
                    SnackbarManager.show(
                            Snackbar.with(mContext)
                                    .text(R.string.add_favr)
                                    .textColor(Color.WHITE)
                                    .color(Color.RED)
                   .duration(Snackbar.SnackbarDuration.LENGTH_SHORT));
                    //End of SnackBack
                    favImage.setTag("red");
                    favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                }
            }
                 else {
                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mContext, feedItemList.get(getItemCount() - 1));

                    favImage.setTag("grey");
                    favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                //SnackBack
                SnackbarManager.show(
                        Snackbar.with(mContext)
                                .text(R.string.remove_favr)
                                .textColor(Color.WHITE)
                                .color(Color.RED)                     .duration(Snackbar.SnackbarDuration.LENGTH_SHORT).animation(false));
                //End of SnackBack
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a couple of days ago - the reason is that you have not updated your feedItemList with the applicable changes. If you update the list by setting some of the member variables (like setExcerpt()) of the Latest class once it has change, your recyclerview will work properly.